# How to insert the first element in a doubly linked list in Java

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I've been looking at various posts, but I can't seem to figure this out - How do you insert an element into an empty doubly linked list? (I can't visualize an empty DLL.) I want to read things from a file and insert them into a DLL, and I also have a method to add the objects to help with this.

```
public void add(ListNode prev, Object object, ListNode next){
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(prev, object, next);
    prev.setNext(newNode);  
    newNode.setPrevious(prev);
    newNode.setNext(next);
    next.setPrevious(newNode);
}
```

In my method where I read the objects and insert them,

```
int currNum = scanner.nextInt();
DoublyLL dll = new DoublyLL();
ListNode curr = dll.getFirst(); //start at beginning of list
ListNode prev = null;

if(curr == null){   //if the list is empty
    ListNode first = new ListNode(curr, currNum, null);
    dll.getFirst().setValue(first); //returns a null-pointer exception
}
```

The last line makes a null-pointer exception. So how do you insert the first element? Do you use add()? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to do something like `dll.setFirst(<some non-null object>)` and then do that last line. It is obviously `null` there (because you just tested for this condition in the `if` statement). You don't need to set some value into `first`, you need to first instantiate `first` here.

Comment: I think this line `dl.getFirst().setValue(0);` (or anything like it) doesn't work because: `public void setValue(Object newVal)
 {
  value =newVal;
 }` and value is null, though `newVal` is not. This method is not supposed to be changed - do you have any idea how to go around this?

Answer (score 0):

You just point the header to it
header=new Node(null,currNum,null);

Comment: That is not possible in this case - the only way to do that is the way I coded it originally. (The header is retrieved by `.getFirst()`, and its value is set with `.setValue()`.) So, for example, `dll.getFirst() = first` doesn't work, of course.

Comment: You do not set the Value of header,you just point it to a node. 
so what you need to do is .getFirst()=new Node(null,currNum,null);